# How to Generate JHipster Entities with @Version Annotation?

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster, spring-data-rest

I need JHipster to generate entities with @Version annotation through JDL studio.

So far, I could find this [link](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/6275) but only with suggestions.

Is there a directive to generate Entities with `@Version` whether in `AbstractAuditingEntity` or in each entity?

Comment: No there is no such thing in JDL

Comment: No workaround? Is it possible to add @version attribute manually ?

Comment: Of course, once the code is generated, it's yours and you can change everything you need.